# Select earliest contact time from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare for the same value in `email` and `email_join` columns, which one has the earliest time by comparing `atlas_interest` and `created_at` columns.

[image]

For example, `matt@example.com` contacted twice, the contacted time are in `atlas_interest` and `created_at` columns. The contact time in `atlast_interest` is earlier. Therefore it will be selected.

`katia@example.com` has no value on "email" and "atlas_interest". Therefore, `created_at` will be selected as the earliest contact time automatically.

The expected output will be:

```
email              earliest_time
-------------------------------------------
matt@example.com   2018-08-12 19:16:17.000
eli@example.com    2018-08-14 14:06:30.000
katia@example.com  2018-08-14 14:11:30.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the value only appear in either `email` or `email_join`, you can use `coalesce()` on it to return the first not null value

After that it is simply `GROUP BY` with `MIN ()` on the time column

```
SELECT email        = COALESCE(email, email_join),
       earlist_time = MIN(COALESCE(atlas_interest, created_at))
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY COALESCE(email, email_join)
```